# Toolbar in CollapsingToolbarLayout not inheriting fontFamily from AppTheme

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-appbarlayout

I'm struggling with my custom `Toolbar`, in particular with its font style. The font family inherited of the toolbar title isn't the expected one (the one set for the app), but it's the default android "Roboto".

My xml layout:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/ctlArticleHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarCollapsed"
    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarExpanded"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
    app:toolbarId="@+id/tbNavigation">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSectionImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

     <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/tbNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="start"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        tools:title="Lorem ipsum"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

My styles.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/spoof</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBaseBlack</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Is that an expected behavior? Everything is working fine for the rest of the app. Am I supposed to force the font family in a dedicated style for the toolbar and duplicating the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to set font type programmatically from my fragment. 
Setting the style from xml helped with the layout preview (working as expected), however it doesn't work at runtime.

So, in my fragment I have:

```
ctlArticleHeader.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.spoof))
ctlArticleHeader.setExpandedTitleTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.spoof))
```

By doing that the font is "forced" programmatically and it's correctly applied in my layout

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom style for the title:

```
  <style name="CustomTitleCollapsed" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
      <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/....</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CustomTitleExpanded" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Design.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/....</item>
  </style>
```

Then applying the style into the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CustomTitleCollapsed"
    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CustomTitleExpanded"
    ../>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, the only thing that seems working seems to be appending a textview to the toolbar used as a ViewGroup. Even forcing the theme with your solution the title keeps Roboto as font

Comment: Are you using an AppBar with a style? And you are using a Toolbar or you are using it as suppportActionBar ?

Comment: I do not have an appbar in my app, the app is single activity (navigation components) and I'm not setting the toolbar as supportActionBar, I'm manually doing popstack back when necessary

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I spoke too early, the preview of the toolbar is correct (taking font), but it doesn't work at runtime (Roboto)!

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi You omitted an important info. The Toolbar is inside a CollapsingToolbar! It is different!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201321/discussion-between-nicola-gallazzi-and-gabriele-mariotti).

Answer (score 0):

in style add

```
   <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font</item>
```

create res>font>my_font.xml

my_font.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/fontnormal" <!--font file(.ttf)-->
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/fontnormal" <!--font file(.ttf)-->
        />
</font-family>
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work and android:font is available only from api 26

Comment: remove android:font there is another  app:font="@font/fontnormal"  available